# Concurrently parse in-memory xml tree with lxml

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, lxml

Say I have a program that looks like this:

```
from lxml import etree

class ParseXmlFile(object):
    def __init__(self, xml_to_parse):
        self.xml = etree.parse(xml_to_parse)

    def a(self):
        return self.xml.xpath('//something')

    def b(self):
        return self.xml.xpath('//something-else')
```

lxml frees the GIL, so it should be possible to run `a` and `b` concurrently in separate threads or processes.

From the lxml docs:

> lxml frees the GIL (Python's global interpreter lock) internally when parsing from disk and memory...The global interpreter lock (GIL) in Python serializes access to the
>   interpreter, so if the majority of your processing is done in Python
>   code (walking trees, modifying elements, etc.), your gain will be
>   close to zero. The more of your XML processing moves into lxml,
>   however, the higher your gain. If your application is bound by XML
>   parsing and serialisation, or by very selective XPath expressions and
>   complex XSLTs, your speedup on multi-processor machines can be
>   substantial.

I have done little to no work with multithreading.

Your run of the mill multiprocessing implementation would use something like `multiprocessing.Pool().map()`, which seems to be of no use here since I have a list of functions and a single argument rather than a single function and a list of arguments. Attempting to wrap each function in another function and then multiprocess as described in one of the answers raises the following exception:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Is it possible to do what I'm describing? If so, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991860/unable-to-pass-an-lxml-etree-object-to-a-separate-process

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't understand how this helps. In and of itself what you linked to doesn't answer my question. In any event the error I experience with the answer below is due to functions not being pickle-able. Registering etree with the pickler would not solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are data, so you can do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f1(xml):
  print "applying f1 to xml"

def f2(xml):
  print "applying f2 to xml"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = "the xml"

    def applyf(f):
       f(xml)

    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(applyf, [f1, f2]))
```

Comment: `cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Comment: The code above runs without any errors under python 2.7. How are you getting that error?