# Multiprocessing pool and queues

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

I am using multiprocessing with pools. I need to pass a structure as argument to a function that has to be used in separate processes. I am facing an issue with the mapping functions of the `multiprocessing.Pool`, since I cannot duplicate neither `Pool.Queue`, nor `Pool.Array`. This structure is to be used on the fly to log the result of each terminated process. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue, Array
import itertools
import time

def do_work(number, out_queue=None):
    if out_queue is not None:
        print "Treated nb ", number
        out_queue.append("Treated nb " + str(number))
    return 0


def multi_run_wrapper(iter_values):
    return do_work(*iter_values)

def test_pool():
    # Get the max cpu
    nb_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nb_proc)
    total_tasks = 16
    tasks = range(total_tasks)

    out_queue= Queue()  # Use it instead of out_array and change out_queue.append() into out_queue.put() in the do_work() function.
    out_array = Array('i', total_tasks)
    iter_values = itertools.izip(tasks, itertools.repeat(out_array))
    results = pool.map_async(multi_run_wrapper, iter_values)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print results._value
    while not out_queue.empty():
        print "queue: ", out_queue.get()
    print "out array: \n", out_array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_pool()
```

I need to launch a worker in a detached process and to pass my output queue as argument. I also want to specify the pool containing a limited number of running processes. For that I am using the `pool.map_async()` function. Unfortunately the piece of code above gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 77, in __getstate__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 52, in assert_spawning
    ' through inheritance' % type(self).__name__
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

I believe it is because a `Queue` cannot be copied, ever, as I read in the doc.
Then I thought of making the queue a global variable so that I would not need to pass it anynmore, but that would be so messy in my opinion. I also thought of using a `multiprocessing.Array` instead

```
out_array = Array('i', total_tasks)
```

but the same error would be risen as with queues:

```
# ...
RuntimeError: SynchronizedArray objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

I need to use this feature - use of multiprocessing and exchanging informations from subprocesses - 
in a relatively big software so I want my code to remain clean and tidy.

How can I pass the queue to my worker in an elegant way?

Of course, any other way of dealing with the main specification is welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` will not accept a `multiprocessing.Queue` as an argument in its work queue.  I believe this is because it internally uses queues to send data back and forth to the worker processes.  There are a couple workarounds:

1) Do you really need to use a queue?  One advantage of the `Pool` function is that their return values are sent back to the main processes.  It is generally better to iterate over the return values from a pool than to use a separate queue.  This also avoids the race condition introduce by checking `queue.empty()`

2) If you must use a `Queue`, you can use one from `multiprocessing.Manager`.  This is a proxy to a shared queue which can be passed as an argument to the `Pool` functions.

3) You can pass a normal `Queue` to worker processes by using an [initializer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) when creating the `Pool`(like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843313). This is kinda hacky.

**The race condition** I mentioned above comes from:

```
while not out_queue.empty():
    print "queue: ", out_queue.get()
```

When you have worker processes filling your queue, you can have the condition where your queue is currently empty because a worker is about to put something into it.  If you check `.empty()` at this time you will end early.  A better method is to put *sentinal* values in your queue to signal when you are finished putting data into it.

Comment: You gave me different valuable tips thank you. Rest assured, the race condition is used as a dummy test ;)

Comment: it would accept it if it is passed as init. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827065/can-i-use-a-multiprocessing-queue-in-a-function-called-by-pool-imap?rq=1)