# Multiprocessing Pool initializer fails pickling

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to use the `multiprocessing.Pool` to implement a multithread application. To share some variables I am using a `Queue` as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827065/can-i-use-a-multiprocessing-queue-in-a-function-called-by-pool-imap):

```
def get_prediction(data):
    #here the real calculation will be performed
    ....


def mainFunction():
    def get_prediction_init(q):
        print("a")
        get_prediction.q = q

    queue = Queue()
    pool = Pool(processes=16, initializer=get_prediction_init, initargs=[queue,])

if __name__== '__main__':
    mainFunction()
```

This code is running perfectly on a Debian machine, but is not working at all on another Windows 10 device. It fails with the error

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'mainFunction.<locals>.get_prediction_init'
```

I do not really know what exactly is causing the error. How can I solve the problem so that I can run the code on the Windows device as well?

EDIT: The problem is solved if I create the `get_predediction_init` function on the same level as the `mainFunction`. It has only failed when I defined it as an inner function. Sorry for the confusion in my post.

Comment: I see 2 dots on  `mainFunction..get_prediction_init`

Comment: Unsure if this is the cause of the issue, but `multiprocessing` code should be shielded by `if __name__ == '__main__':` [in Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Comment: Sorry! I added some more code to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Please post a complete, executable program, as I did for you.  When I guess at what the missing pieces are in your edited code, it still works fine for me on Windows.

Comment: @TimPeters can confirm the error from the posted code on Windows 7 at least. Your minimal example works, the posted code throws `PicklingError`.

Comment: @TimPeters Sorry (again). I made mistake in my first edit with the copying & pasting of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in something you *haven't* shown us.  For example, it's a mystery where "mainFunction" came from in the `AttributeError` message you showed.

Here's a complete, executable program based on the fragment you posted.  Worked fine for me under Windows 10 just now, under Python 3.6.1 (I'm guessing you're using Python 3 from your `print` syntax), printing "a" 16 times:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_prediction(data):
    #here the real calculation will be performed
    pass

def get_prediction_init(q):
    print("a")
    get_prediction.q = q

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = mp.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=16, initializer=get_prediction_init, initargs=[queue,])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

### Edit

And, based on your edit, this program also works fine for me:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_prediction(data):
    #here the real calculation will be performed
    pass

def get_prediction_init(q):
    print("a")
    get_prediction.q = q

def mainFunction():
    queue = mp.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=16, initializer=get_prediction_init, initargs=[queue,])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainFunction()
```

### Edit 2

And now you've moved the definition of `get_prediction_init()` into the body of `mainFunction`.  *Now* I can see your error :-)

As shown, define the function at module level instead.  Trying to pickle local function objects can be a nightmare.  Perhaps someone wants to fight with that, but not me ;-)

Comment: I edited the post and added more information about the mainFunction.

Comment: Alright! Do you know why it fails on Windows but works on Debian?

Comment: Answering that is a form of "fight with that" ;-)  I don't even want to try.  Real answers tend to get deep in the weeds, and in the end you have to make the functions global anyway.

Comment: But I'll give the short course:  on Debian `Pool` creates worker processes via `fork()` - pickle has nothing to do with that.  On Windows `fork()` isn't available, and objects have to be pickled for worker processes to unpickle.  On Debian, they're simply inherited from the parent process.